# Problema getServerSideProps nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm learning next, I'm making a simple website with a form for entering users and displaying users always on the same page. the insertion I managed to do it with an api call but I'm not understanding the get of the data, I made a getserversideprops function in the page, in the terminal I see the data but the page continues to turn and does not load, how can I do? thank you all

page code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home({utenti}) {
  return (
    <>
    <form method="POST" action='/api/sendInfo'>
      <label>Nome</label>
      <input type="text" name="nome"></input>

      <label>Cognome</label>
      <input type="text" name="cognome"></input>

      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email"></input>

      <button type="submit">Invia</button>
    </form>

    <div>
      <p>Select Utenti</p>
      
        <button type="submit" action = '/api/getInfo'  method="GET"> prendi utenti</button>
      
      
    </div>

    </>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps () {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch('http:127.0.0.1:3000/api/getInfo')
  const data =  res.json()
  console.log ("Questi sono i data");
  console.log (data);
  // res.json(data)
  // Pass data to the page via props
  
  return { 
    utenti: {
       utenti: data 
     } 
  }
  
}
```

api http:127.0.0.1:3000/api/getInfo code:

```
import connection from "../../db";

export default async(req, res) => {
  try{
    
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM Utenti'
    const result = await connection.query(
      query,
      
    );
  
    console.log(result);
    
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  
 
  res.redirect("/");  
}
```

Comment: I can't find the "getServerSideProps" function in your posted code

Comment: You need `const data =  await res.json()`

Comment: sorry, it's in place of getStaticProps

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks, i have another problem, it goes in loop and keeps sending me data

Answer (score 0):

`res.json` returns a `Promise`, so you need to `await` it.

```js
const data = await res.json();
```

Comment: thanks, i have another problem, it goes in loop and keeps sending me data